# meaning of the phrase 听你的 and purpose of 的

Tags: grammar, phrase

What does it mean to say 听你的 when someone tells you to do something. And what is the purpose of 的 in this structure?

Comment: In 听你的, 的 is a sentence final particle which strengthens the mood of the sentence. https://medium.com/@glossika/chinese-grammar-how-to-use-modal-particles-18ac19d280c1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

听(listen to)你的(yours) is equivalent to "go with your idea/wish/suggestion/advice". It implies following, obeying, accepting, and agreeing with what is offered by your companion.

"你的 = yours" as opposed to "you = 你".

Answer (score 2):

"听你的" is similar with "It depends on you".

The perosn who said the words may be in a mood.

For example:

When somebody who is arguing with another person.

"听你的" means he or she just don't want to argue anymore.

But in another situation, "听你的" is just the meaning that he or she is very casual

about how things go.

For example:

A : "你想吃炸鸡吗？"   B: "听你的"

Comment: So basically "听你的" has a quite negative meaning?

Comment: @starckman Not actualy, it depends on the communication. In most cases, this sentence is neither good nor bad

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have in mind some situations where 听你的 can even be used to 撒嬌 (in romantic relationships for instance).

Comment: Quote:- "So basically "听你的" has a quite negative meaning?" It depends. It is, in some context, equivalent to the English -- "Whatever", (a favorite of teenagers when answering their parents), which, as @jackson says, is either negative or otherwise depending on the circumstances of the conversation and the tone of course.